# Solaris 11 x86 disable shutdown on ACPI power button

Tags: solaris, acpi

If a x86 Solaris system is not in X11 (text console), it will shutdown, after the power button pressed. How should I disable this? The documentation from Oracle only states that you can power the system off by pressing the power button, but not how to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

It turns out that a daemon called **powerd(1M)** will listening for the power button event by `poll(2)`ing `/dev/power_button` device.

Interesting thing is, it will also checking `gnome-power-manager` process, and skipping shutdown if that process exists; this explains why the shutdown doesn't occur when GNOME (the default desktop in Solaris 11) is running.
Reference: https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/80148899834a4078a2bd348504aa2d6de9752837/usr/src/cmd/power/powerd.c#L1188

**powerd(1M)** is started by **pmconfig(1M)**, which in turn started by `system/power` SMF service; to solve the issue, I just disabled this service, and everything worked just fine:

```
svcadm disable system/power
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Solaris 10 or 11, you can disable ACPI altogether via `eeprom(8)` , and it's the only method I know of. The manual (on my 11.4 machine) says :

```
   acpi-user-options

       A configuration variable that controls the use of Advanced Configu-
       ration  and  Power  Interface (ACPI), a power management specifica-
       tion. The acceptable values for this variable depend on the release
       of the Solaris operating system you are using.

       For  all  releases  of Solaris 10 and Solaris 11, a value of of 0x0
       means that there will be an attempt to use ACPI if it is  available
       on the system. A value of 0x2 disables the use of ACPI.
```

Comment: Hasn't disabling ACPI already gone out of fashion like 15 years ago or so?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it has.

Comment: I known that disabling ACPI will work, but many more important features such as SMP would be lost by doing that...